# How to prepare image dataset in MNIST format

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, mnist

I have trained a neural network model on `MNIST` dataset using the script [mnist_3.1_convolutional_bigger_dropout.py](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mzrui1b46qx4zmz/mnist_3.1_convolutional_bigger_dropout.py?dl=0) provided in this [tutorial](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/tensorflow-without-a-phd/tree/master/tensorflow-mnist-tutorial).

I wanted to test the trained model on the custom dataset, hence I wrote a small script `predict.py` which loads the trained model and feed the data to it. But it's not working.

I believe only resizing the image to `28x28` is not enough, some other preprocessing has to be done in order to make it compatible with `MNIST` standard.

Here is the script that I wrote for testing

**predict.py**

```
from scipy.misc import imread
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import glob

files = glob.glob('data2/*.*')

dig_cont = [cv.imread(fl, 0) for fl in files]

img_data = []
for i in range(len(dig_cont)):
    img = cv.resize(dig_cont[i], (28, 28))  
    img = img.reshape(img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 1)
    img_data.append(img)

print("Restoring Model ...")

sess = tf.Session()

tf_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('model/model.meta')

tf_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('model'))

print("Model restored")

x = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('X:0')
print('x :', x.shape)
y = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('Y:0')
print('y :', y.shape)

dict_data = {x: img_data}

result = sess.run(y, feed_dict=dict_data)
print(result)

sess.close()
```

Detailed error report can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zrnduvaxxi5hnbt/errot.txt?dl=0)